SUMUP integration with curl in php
i'm trying to checkout a SUMUP payment and get allways:
*{"title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.sumup.cloak.controllers.ProcessCheckoutController.chargev1(java.lang.String,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)"} *
$curl = curl_init();

$urlToSend = "https://api.sumup.com/v0.1/checkouts/".checkout_id_from_prev_call;

$curlHeaders  = [
  'Authorization: Bearer '. my_access_token,             
  'Content-Type: application/json'
];

$postData ='{
   "payment_type": "card",
   "card": {
   "name": "Boaty McBoatface",
   "number": "4200000000000042",
   "expiry_month": "12",
   "expiry_year": "23",
   "cvv": "123"
   }
}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $urlToSend);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (urldecode($postData)));        
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

the response will be
Required request body is missing
i'v tried to set teh data as follows too:
$postData = [
   'payment_type' => 'card',
   'card' => [
        'name' => 'Boaty McBoatface',
        'number' => '4200000000000042',
        'expiry_month' => '12',
        'expiry_year' => '23',
        'cvv' => '123'   
   ]                  
];

and then:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (http_build_query($postData))); 

the error stays the same:
Required request body is missing:

The header you're setting implies that is needs to be JSON, so I am mystified as to why you're using urldecode() or http_build_query() functions in either of the situations you've posed. 1. Do not write JSON by hand, use the array from the latter example. 2. Call json_encode() to encode it as JSON.

problem solved:
mask the flds correct.
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"payment_type\": \"card\",\"card\": {\"name\": \"Boaty McBoatface\",\"number\": \"4200000000000042\",\"expiry_month\": \"12\",\"expiry_year\": \"23\",\n          \"cvv\": \"123\"}}");

by  the way here is an tool to convert curl into php syntax, this showed me the right way.
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
